# Create a log link in Test case report

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to embed a log URL in report.html generated by Robotframework after test case execution. I have the below code:

```
${LogStr}=     Catenate     "Error Log created: "     <a href="./logs/${test_name}.txt">Test Logs</a>
Fail    ${LogStr}
```

But the log renders something like below:

```
Error Log created: <a href="./logs/test_xxx_data.txt">Test Logs</a>
```

View Source extract os report.html file:

```
Error Log created:  &lt;a href=\"./logs/test_xxx_data.txt\"&gt;Test Logs&lt;/a&gt;
```

Also I was assuming that the string "Test Logs" will be a hyperlink to test log but it does not happens so - they are just normal strings printed in report.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the [message with `*HTML*`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fail) to instruct the framework the content should be injected as html:

```
${LogStr}=     Catenate     *HTML*Error Log created:     <a href="./logs/${test_name}.txt">Test Logs</a>
Fail    ${LogStr}
```